# How to filter for a list of email subjects in outlook with python

Tags: python, list, email, filter, outlook

I'm working on a project to read emails that are using different email subjects in outlook.

I have a list of email subjects, may I know how should I perform the coding to filter for a list of matches?

[filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison) I am referring to this documentation to restrict the filter, but there's no example on how to filter using a list instead of a string comparison.

can any masters here advice on this?

```
#example of the code
email_sub = ["Data File", "Confidential", "18-01 Excel", "Purchasing", "Purchase Trend"]

#set filter
Filter = "[Subject] = 'email_sub'"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's inbuilt `filter` function.
Something like the following should work assuming you have a list of emails.

```py
emails = []
email_sub = ["Data File", "Confidential", "18-01 Excel", "Purchasing", "Purchase Trend"]

def subject_filter(email):
    if email.subject in email_sub:
        return True
    else:
        return False

filtered_emails = filter(emails, subject_filter)
```

You can also do it more succinctly using list comprehension

```py
[email for email in emails if email.subject in email_sub]
```

Comment: That would be as bad as it gets from the performance point of view: never loop through all items in a folder, use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict`.

Comment: hi @DmitryStreblechenko, may i know if Item.FindNext can handle a list of subjects? As I tried read thru the documentation, but I have less knowledge in VBA..

Comment: hi @theundeadmonk, thanks a lot on the suggestion, I tried with list comprehension its running but it only shows the first email after the loop..

Answer (score 0):

Create a filter with multiple conditions connected with the `Or` operator:

```
Filter = "[Subject] = 'email_sub' Or [Subject] = 'email_sub 2'"
```

Comment: hi @Dmitry, i tried with this as well., but is not running and I think this not suitable for my case as I might have a very long filtration.

Comment: By "not running", do you mean you get an error? Or that no matches are returned? Does your filter work with a single match?